# how to disable the functionality to hide/show the chart when user click ChartLegend with ShieldUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, data-visualization, shieldui

Here we have an Example of a [ShieldUI Chart](http://jsbin.com/OkEPIvU/1/edit?html,js,output), does someone if it's possible to disable the functionality to hide/show the chart when user click the CharLegent? I mean as you can see when user hits "Braking Distance" the yellow chart has been hidden. I want to disable that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the event from being triggered in a `legendSeriesClick` event handler function, as shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chart").shieldChart({
        ...
        events: {
            legendSeriesClick: function (e) {
                // stop the series item click event, so that 
                // user clicks do not toggle visibility of the series
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

A complete example is shown in this [chart demo](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/area-chart/export).